# does not give results with $ git push heroku master, I am applying boostrap, ruby on rails and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a problem when placed git push heroku master, show this error:

```
To git@heroku.com:salty-lake-2991.git  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:salty-lake-2991.git'
```

My project at Github: https://github.com/angelis888/pagina1

I am working bootstrap-ruby on rails-heroku.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: ok thanks Daniel, i try with twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gemfile you have a line saying

```
joya 'bootstrap-sass...'
```

That should say Gem

Try that first and see if the error message changes.

Comment: thanks Nikesh, i have: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

there is no gem kgio like this that runs on window, that window is the worst to schedule.
 error occurred while installing kgio (2.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.